# Eclipse 3.2; Subversion 1.5: compatible Subclipse or Subversive version?

Tags: svn, subclipse, subversive, eclipse-3.2

I'm trying to access a Subversion repository with an integration plugin in Eclipse 3.2.2.

(Okay, so I'm using [EasyEclipse](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/server-java.html) Server Java, it's just easier than setting up all of those plugins every time I have to setup a new development environment...)

If there is no solution to this, I'd just as soon get to setting up an environment from scratch. (I'm guessing the answer is no...)

So my question is, is there any version of Subclipse or Subversive that can be used with Eclipse 3.2 and Subversion 1.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Subclipse [website](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), Subclipse 1.4.7 (latest) is used for SVN 1.5 and Eclipse 3.2

Comment: Okay, yeah that did the trick.  It was the lastest version, and I also had to uncheck the integration option as I'm not using Mylyn...

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Subclipse 1.4.6 without any problems on 1.5 SVN repositories in eclipse 3.2.*

Hope this helps there's a couple of issues with 1.4 clients and 1.5 repositories and i've actually seen people break there workspace due to Subclipse mixups so beware :)